# Sql returning date time without seconds and milliseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

my this code returns date time but with seconds milliseconds , i don't want milliseconds and seconds. I tried but not working, help. In this format.
Output:

Code:

```
Set @DateFrom = Convert(date,(Select min(ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime) from ReceivedMessages))
      Set @DateTo = Convert(date,(Select max(ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime) from ReceivedMessages))

      SELECT [ID]
      ,LEFT(REPLACE(convert(varchar, ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime, 113), ' ','/'), 11) + ' ' +
       RIGHT(REPLACE(convert(varchar, ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime, 113), ' ','/'), 12)
       as RecievingDate
      ,[FromMobileNo]
      ,[Message],
       [IsComplaint]
      FROM [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
      where Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)>= @DateFrom AND Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)<= @DateTo
      AND IsComplaint = 2
```

Comment: [The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#GettingRidOfTimePortion) is a link someone provided me for an earlier question. It helped me understand a lot more about datetime. You might specifically be interested in [Getting rid of the time portion](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#GettingRidOfTimePortion)

Answer (score 3):

Try this, but replace GETDATE() with your time

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(), 121)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @dtime datetime;
set @dtime = getdate();

select REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(11), @dtime, 113), ' ', '/') 
     + RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(17), @dtime, 113), 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can round datetime to the nearest minute like this:

```
DECLARE @CaptureDate datetime
SELECT @CaptureDate = DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, DATEADD(second, 30 - DATEPART(second, GETDATE() + '00:00:30.000'), GETDATE())), 0)
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @CaptureDate, 120)
```

Change GETDATE() to your date fields as applicable.

Comment: woh it works but problem is that now it returns seconds part as :00, i don't want this, i want clear datetime upto minute part

Comment: Edited to exclude the seconds zeros.